# Can't add a String[] to an ArrayList<Car>

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add a string to an ArrayList but it won't allow me to do so. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how it can be fixed?

Here's my code for the CarApplication Class:

```
public class CarApplication extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

String[][] records = {
           {"1", "Honda", "Civic", "Silver", "2009", "3500.00", "civic09.jpg", "(087) 3654286"},
           {"2", "Opel", "Corsa", "Red", "2007", "3100.00", "corsa07.jpg", "(086) 2951730"},
         6640085"}
};
int currentItem;

public CarApplication() {
    super("Motor Trader Application");
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        //to store records in array list;
        carList.add(records[i]);

    }

 }
```

I want to keep my arrayList of type Car but be able to add the records to it.

Comment: `ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();` Is that ArrayList holding strings?

Comment: no empty i want to add the records string to it

Comment: It is an empty ArrayList yes.  But what is it declared with, Strings? Look closely (or just read the answers since they spoiled it.)

Comment: Can you add your car class?

Comment: Post the code of the Car class if you have.

Comment: @chancea seems like maybe a copy-paste or a dissimilar scenario in a tutorial is causing the confusion here ... meaning (s)he may not know that the `<type>` declares the type the `ArrayList` is constructed to hold.

Comment: @MikeLyons I know I was trying to lead the OP to the answer themselves to see if they could pick that up

Comment: I do understand that what type the arraylist needs to be

Comment: @lulikuku the arraylist is correct.  It is the 2d Array that is not

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a type `String[]` to an array list that expects a type `Car`.  You need to instead add `Car` objects to that list.

Instead, use `ArrayList<String[]> carList= new ArrayList<String[]>;`

If you want to instead put cars in your array list, then convert the strings you're trying to add to Car Objects by constructing them one by one or creating constructor of Car object that takes an ArrayList as a parameter.

The main idea, above all here, is to stay consistent with your data types when creating data structures.

Comment: This does solve the exact question the OP is asking.  However, seeing that his code compiled with `ArrayList<Car>` that probably means he should be making `Car`'s not `String[]` So probably should tell him to make instances of cars.

Comment: that's because i have a car class and its based for it

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayList` is constructed to only take values of the type `Car` not `String`

Answer (score 1):

Your array list can only allows car objects. Change your loop code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            //to store records in array list;
            carList.add(new Car(Integer.parseInt(records[i][0]),records[i][1],records[i][3],Integer.parseInt(records[i][4]),Double.parseDouble(records[i][5]),records[i][6],records[i][7]);

        }
```

Comment: Wont work unless you translate the strings to int's and double's when needed

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the fact you have 2 data structures holding on to your `Cars`.  You have an `ArrayList<Car>` and a `String[][]`.  It should be clear that the `ArrayList` Holds only `Cars` while the `String[][]` is holding a 2 Dimensional Array of `Strings`.  Seeing the values in the `String` array could represent cars you probably only need to make either an `ArrayList` or a 1 Dimensional `Car[]`.

The `Car[]` Would look like :

```
Car[] records = {
           new Car(1, "Honda", "Civic", "Silver", 2009, 3500.00, "civic09.jpg", "(087) 3654286"),
           new Car(2, "Opel", "Corsa", "Red", 2007, 3100.00, "corsa07.jpg", "(086) 2951730"),
           new Car(3, "Ford", "Mondeo", "Silver", 2008, 5500.00, "mondeo08.jpg", "(087) 6023159"),
           new Car(4, "Nissan", "Primera", "Dark grey", 2007, 4800.00, "primera07.jpg", "(085) 9042456"),
           new Car(5, "Ford", "Focus", "Metallic blue", 2009, 3700.00, "focus09.jpg", "(086) 6640085")
};
```

The `ArrayList` Version you would be able to add dynamically as many cars you want in your `CarrApplication()` method as such:

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public CarApplication() {
        super("Motor Trader Application");
               carList.add(new Car(1, "Honda", "Civic", "Silver", 2009, 3500.00, "civic09.jpg", "(087) 3654286");
               carList.add(new Car(2, "Opel", "Corsa", "Red", 2007, 3100.00, "corsa07.jpg", "(086) 2951730");
               carList.add(new Car(3, "Ford", "Mondeo", "Silver", 2008, 5500.00, "mondeo08.jpg", "(087) 6023159");
               carList.add(new Car(4, "Nissan", "Primera", "Dark grey", 2007, 4800.00, "primera07.jpg", "(085) 9042456");
               carList.add(new Car(5, "Ford", "Focus", "Metallic blue", 2009, 3700.00, "focus09.jpg", "(086) 6640085");

    currentItem = 0;    
}
```

Unless you have a reason for holding on to both data structures I would try to only store data in one location when possible.  And note that Arrays (i.e. `Car[]`) You cannot add to later on, but `ArrayList<Car>` you can.  So it depends on if you are using a static list of cars or if you need to continually add to the list later in the code.